# Shaping Bezier objects and applying Physics collisions?

Tags: animation, mesh, physics, collision, bezier-curves

Logo animation project
First part is dropping chromed tubes on a floor, let them bounce and roll a bit. The rolling stops at frame 90.

Second part is for the lighting to go dark, and the tubes emit a neon glow. 
Tubes then animate shape into an outline of a frog.

[image: Chrome tubes prior to animation]
The problem is that I am using Mesh Objects for the falling tubes, but cannot shape them like a Bezier Line.

Alternatively, I can shape Bezier Tubes for part 2 as I wish, but cannot apply a Collision physics to them so that they bounce and roll on the floor in part 1.

My current solution is to create part 1 until frame 90 using Mesh Tubes. For part 2 I create duplicate Bezier Tubes in the same precise orientation as the Mesh Tubes at frame 90. I then animate the Bezier Tubes to change their shapes from frame 90 to the end. Any suggestions for a better solution are welcome. Placing the Bezier Tubes is quite tedious.

A partial solution is to use >both<. First the mesh object for the bounce and roll. I put these on a layer. Second the bezier objects for the shape animations. I put these on a second layer after alignment with the mesh tubes on layer one.

Comment: Could you use non-rendering physics bodies that bezier curves track using hooks?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a shower hose with correct physics](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/109448/create-a-shower-hose-with-correct-physics)

Comment: You could also use a cylinder mesh object with a curve modifier for the tubes

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you *can* have soft body physics on Bezier Curve Objects as detailed on the [Quick Noodle Physics in Blender Tutorial Youtube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lg7jxAMs60Q)

According to the video the trick is using a highly subdivided curve, there must be lots of actual vertex (display subdivisions are insufficient), many of the settings are ignored.

You should turn off *Soft Body Goal*, and tweak the parameters under *Soft Body Self Collision* like *Ball Size* and *Stiffness*.

Some other object set to *Collision Physics* type must be present at the scene for interaction.

[image]

Also see related [Are curve physics possible?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48801/are-curve-physics-possible)