# Rope dynamic physics

Tags: animation, bezier-curves, physics, rigid-body-simulation, cloth-simulation

So I'm creating an animation and I've faced a serious problem. There's a moving object and I want a rope to be attached to this object while its moving, and the other end of the rope should be connected to somewhere else offscreen. I've used some techniques I've seen on youtube. But none of them were good for my case. Some tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Please specify what you have tried, and more importantly why it didn't work. I'd hate to suggest something you've tried already or that is not "good for your case"

Comment: I did 2 things. 1) I created a bunch of cubes then connected them together and then hooked them to a curve. In this case, the rope would stretch. 2) I created a curve then gave it a cloth modifier but I was not able to get it to work(It would connect to the moving object but the other end would not stay at a  fixed position.

Comment: [How to simulate a rope?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/97749/how-to-simulate-a-rope/98438#98438)

Comment: Thanks. It solved my problem. I made the mistake of hooking the vertices directly to an object rather than to an empty then making it a child of another object.