# Curve hook to mesh

Tags: modifiers

I am trying to make sails for ship. But I stuck on problem. At first I should mention that I am doing it according to: 
[How to simulate a rope?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/97749/how-to-simulate-a-rope) [How do I attach rope to a mesh](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/133893/how-do-i-attach-rope-to-a-mesh)

I succesfully hook curve to my sails and bot are moving when i drag this "hook", BUT When i start simulate wind into sails with cloth modi. and curve with soft body modi., the curve just fly off and it doesnt stick together.
Please do you have any advice?

[image: Simulation in progress when curve flew off hooks.]

Answer (score 0):

To do it you should pin the sail to e.g. empties put at the corner vertices thereof. You should have the pin option in the cloth sim menu.

EDIT: Set sail's vertex weight to 1 after you applied the curve modifier.

Comment: Maybe I dont understand what should I do. In cloth sim menu is "pin group" but there I have points for attachement upper edge of my sails... so I cant add pin for curve. But it is possible that I dont understand what I should do. Sorry I am still a lot of learning about blender :D