# How to transform a mesh with many objects?

Tags: transforms

I want to transform (location, rotation, scale and deform mesh) a triangle with 3 animated objects, each vertex of the triangle follows one object.

On this screenshot there are one tirangle whose follows 3 animated cubes that move from position 1 to position 2.

Is there a simple method to do that.

For example by join (or set parent ) each vertex of triangle with each object, but I don't know how to do this!

Thank you !

[image]

Comment: You need to add some more information to your question.
It's kind of unclear what you are trying to do. Maybe add some screenshots and/or sketches.

Comment: Can use the method outlined here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/133893/how-do-i-attach-rope-to-a-mesh  Add a hook to each apex of tri mesh, then vertex parent each  hook to cubes.

Comment: Thanks very much @batFINGER !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hook and Vertex Parent.**

Triangle in edit mode.

[image]

Select each vert, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> and choose add new hook.  This creates an empty at the vert.

Repeat for other two verts.

For each empty,

[image]

Select empty, <kbd>Shift</kbd> select cube to parent to.
Go into edit mode, select one, two or three vertices then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> To make vertex parent.

Note could cut out the "middle man" empty and hook directly to cubes.

Comment: With this method, the origin of the triangle stays fixed during the animation.   Is there a way to move also the origin, pivot of the triangle?     In other words, is it possible to convert this Hook Modifier to the 2D curves (location, rotation, and scale) of this triangle in Graph Editor ?