# How to convert an object transformed by a Hook Modifier to an object with Loc,Rot,Scal Transformations?

Tags: modifiers, transforms, coordinates

I create one triangle whose is transformed by 3 animated cubes.

To realize this, I use "Hook Modifier" (as proposed in this [*topic*](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/172986/how-to-transform-a-mesh-with-many-objects) ) , each vertex of the triangle is associated to a hook and each hook is parented to a cube. Each cube is animated.

During the animation (from position 1 to position 2 in the screenshot), the origin and the vertices of the triangle stay in the same position.

Is there a method to move the origin and eventualy the vertices of the triangle when the cubes move ?

In other words, is it possible to convert this Hook Modifier with animated cubes to get Location , Rotation and Scale keyframes of this triangle ?

(Rem: it is the same problem after applied this modifier as shape keys )

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parent both your object and the hooks to an empty, that would take care of the origin. 
You can also use the empty if you want to animate all the cubes relative to each other.

However:
I would strongly suggest you just use an armature with 3 bones and put one vertex to weight 1, and the other 2 to 0 for each according bone. Hooks are dangerous, they have no rest position, and an armature keeps everything neat and tidy.

You'll probably need to check a more detailed tutorial on this, but here is the breakdown:
Add -> Armature
In edit mode on your triangle, select one of the vertices -> cursor to selected.
In edit mode on armature press `SHIFT` A, it will create a bone at the cursor location. Call the bone 'A', repeat for 2 other verts.
Object mode, select object, then armature -> CTRL P -> with empty groups.
Edit mode on your plane select a vertex, select the group of the bone it's supposed to be dragged by make sure weight is at 1.0 and press assign. 
Take One of your cubes, SHIFT-select the armature, go into pose mode, select the corresponding bone, CTRL P -> active bone, repeat. 
If this was too abstract there's tons of tutorials on that online.

Comment: How , thanks very much @frederik-steinmetz

Comment: Edited my answer, make sure to delete the hook modifiers first.