# Astronaut I made has a physics reactive armature, how do I make the hose collide when it hits the astronaut

Tags: rigging, cloth-simulation

So, I made this astronaut in blender, I named her Myrtle. And I followed this really good YouTube tutorial for making an armature that deforms in reaction to physics like gravity as well as deforming the mesh. The armatures work wonderfully, actually perfectly. My main issue currently is that I can't get the air hose to collide with the astronaut's arm and body, it just passes straight through it.

It looks like this before I press play in blender: [image: before running physics]

Then when I press play it falls down and straight through the arm and into the body: [image: misbehaving mesh]

I'm not sure how to set up collisions or if because I added gravity to my armature for the air hose if I could even do so, if anyone is wondering what tutorial I followed I followed this YouTube tutorial: https://youtu.be/c11l2o5uCQs

I can't figure out how to make the hose less flexible either, I want it to merely react to gravity and sway when the character walks runs etc. But it actually is too string like when I add cloth physics to it.

Comment: Like your character, +1 by the way.

Comment: oh, you accidentally posted this question twice.

Comment: Yeah, I first posted it in the wrong area, I reposted in this one in what I believe to be the correct category, I'm sorry about the spam. As for what version of blender I'm using, I am stubborn and still using the outmoded blender 2.79 any idea how to make my astronaut's oxygen tube collide with the mesh of the arm and body. I don't know if following that YouTube tutorial and making the armature respond to gravity will affect the mesh's ability to collide with other meshes, currently the oxygen tube just passes through the arm and body.

Comment: not sure, but i hope you can find an answer.  I haven't watched the video, but could you tell me generally what you did to make gravity effect it?  was it rigid bodies?

Comment: The YouTube video explains it better than I ever could, but I'll try anyway...

Comment: Basically I created the mesh for my object that I wanted to react to gravity

Comment: Then I created a mesh of just vertices with connections but no faces in the length of the mesh, as close as possible to the center of the mesh I wanted to deform.

Comment: And I went and paired empties, 'spherical empty objects' to the vertices that were in the mesh that I'd apply the gravity to. Then I added an armature, made the mesh a child of the meshes without faces, then parented the mesh without faces to the armature after applying cloth physics to it.

Comment: wow, that's a pretty hefty simulation.  I'll probably have to watch the video :)

Comment: For a hose, you could use a softbody simulation on a string of edges in place of your armature, with a Skin modifier to give it thickness - similar to https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/98438/29586. This should allow it to react to gravity while also being able to react to collisions.

Comment: I just thought of something, if this is a cloth simulator, it should react to collisions.  have you tried adding a collision modifier to your astronaut?

Comment: Thankyou that sounds exactly like a perfect answer. I will try that and update you if it works. :)

Comment: As far as adding a collision to my astronaut I'm pretty lost the functions aren't very clear about how they function, I'm using blender 2.79 if it helps.

Comment: Strange... still doesn't want to react to collisions at all, I have tried all the suggestions given here but I must be doing something wrong, it still passes through the astronaut's arm and body.

Comment: It didn't work despite me adding collisions to the astronaut, and the softbody physics made the air hose liquify when played back on blender. If anyone has any ideas that might help I'd love to hear them pls.