# How to make a rope constraints two mesh and swinging?

Tags: animation, soft-body

[image]

I've try make a kendama animation, when make the rope I want the endpoints of this rope to connect two meshes while following their movement and swinging looks realistic. I think use bone wasn't a good choice, pls tell me how would you do this animation if it were you, thanks!

Comment: Have you tried the search at the top? I found a few related questions that could help you, for example https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/97749/how-to-simulate-a-rope just by typing _rope_ in the search field.

Comment: Thanks, I've seen this once and I forgot to read it...Now I feel a little bit awkward