# Simulating piece of cloth between two moving points

Tags: constraints, cloth-simulation

I am trying to simulate a piece of cloth with two points of control. The controllers will move towards each other, leaving the straps to loosen and fall on the ground. I want to then animate the points moving away from each other again as they straighten and lift up the straps.

I have tried using hooks, but they only move the vertices assigned to them

Then I tried using bones to move, but the whole mesh is moving with.

In the attached image, I would like to have point B stay in place while point A moves towards and away from it.

[image: Test with bones]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/97749/how-to-simulate-a-rope

Comment: Thanks, but I think I need to use cloth dynamics instead of soft body due to the strap being a flat surface and there will be close-up shots.

Answer (score 0):

OKay. Got it working. What I was missing was adding a weight map for each hook, instead of only having the pin group as a weight map. Doh!

[image: Solution for each hook]