# Soft Body rope extends infinitely— how to constrain?

Tags: physics, soft-body

I followed [this tutorial](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/97749/how-to-simulate-a-rope) to make a 'cord' that joins two objects in my scene (basically a path with two empties and a soft body modifier). I'm mostly happy with the collision but it seems to extend forever if I stretch it.
I'm new & learning about how to apply physics in Blender— is this behavior just how the soft body modifier works? What other options do I have for creating a cord/rope if I want to explore alternatives that could constrain the two objects within a certain distance?

Video: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHg2w.jpg
[image: Gamecube, cord, and controller]

Thanks for any help you can offer!

Comment: you might want to use a cloth sim for the wire that can't stretch