# How to make fake rope animations

Tags: animation, texturing, rigging, node-editor, extrude

Can you guys give me some advice on how to make animation like that? I want to create an animation very similar to this in the video.
[Rope Animation Example](https://vimeo.com/514668525) Thanks for any advice

[image: video screenshot]

Comment: Your link goes to a page saying: "Sorry, we couldn’t find that page".  How about a search for rope animation in this forum?   One result I get is  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/97749/how-to-simulate-a-rope

Comment: I'm sorry I have fixed the link now