# Why does my rope doesn't follow hooks?

Tags: physics, hook-modifier

I'm trying to link my boat to stick using rope:
[image: rope]
But I want to make my rope physically correct. I found that [answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/98438/143610) but when I'm trying to move empties to right positions, the rope doesn't follow them correctly:
[image: fail]
So, I can't even attach my rope, not to mention tying a knot(

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: hello, could you please share your file (only the useful elements)?

Comment: @moonboots Of course. [File](https://pasteall.org/blend/c4be5752288f428e95a91696be256b28)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have forgotten to assign this tip vertex to the pin group:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hm, I did it. Nothing changed.

Comment: weird, it works for me, see my edit

Comment: I can't understand. I recreated this again: Add path > Subdivide > Convert to mesh > Select first and last vertexes and assign them to vertex group > create hook for that vertexes > Add softbody modifier to mesh > add skin modifier to mesh. Nothing changed. [File](https://pasteall.org/blend/51514a2265434673a2d65b178bd32a31)

Comment: it works in the file you share, put the cursor at the beginning of your timeline and press the spacebar

Comment: Ok, my fault, I did't try to start animation. But the rope still don't follow to empties in realtime, is it possible? Because I can't create a knot like in answer I mention if I'll need to start animation every time.

Comment: it won't correctly follow the empties in real time but when you'll keyframe and play it should work fine (even more when you'll bake)

Comment: Understood. Thank you!