# Softbody with rigid body activated won't interact with other rigid bodies

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation, collision, soft-body

I am trying to do a "simple" thing which turns out quite frustrating.

I want to attach a "rope" between two points and have that rope be a rigid body so it can knock stuff over.

For the rope I've used this technique: [Link to StackExchange Post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/97749/how-to-simulate-a-rope/98438#98438)

My rope consists of a *curve, subdivided and converted into a mesh*. Then I apply the *softbody modifier*, no problem here, works as expected. But no matter where I place the *rigid body modifier (passive, animated)* and which *collision shape* I use (tried them all), the objects **won't collide** with each other. Also setting both objects to *active rigid bodies* and the rope to be animated it did not work.

I also tried to export it as Alembic and import it again onto a model with *rigid body* activated as well but no luck either. This imported model has real faces though as opposed to the initial string of vertices with *softbody* simulation. Still no colliding. See pictures here:

[image: scene overview and used modifier settings]

Comment: I don't know what or how many combinations you might have tried, just be aware that you can't mix rigid body with soft body physics simulations.

Comment: But when using the Alembic file in the MeshCache, shouldn't that at least work? I've tried exporting it as fbx as well but the animation is not properly exported from the softbody.

Comment: If you have baked a simulation to keyframes, for example a rigid body simulation, and you want it to interact with a soft body object, you have to make the former rigid body a collision object and make sure you've removed the rigid body physics. And you should delete the soft body cache. And the Alembic file, well that's a modifier to vary the mesh over time - but it's not creating a "real" mesh to interact with rigid bodies. The mesh used for the rigid body simulation is the one wyou will see when going into _Edit Mode_.