# How to animate a knot

Tags: animation, bones, bezier-curves, cloth-simulation

I need to animate multiple crochet knots such as chain stitches etc. including the crochet needle but without hands. Here is an example [image]

I tried by manually animating curves with hooks, but found them difficult to control.(the curve has either too many or not enough segments)
What would be the best way to go about it? Should I rig it, if yes anyone has any good tutorials? Or should I use physics simulations?

I searched a lot but haven't found any good information on it yet.

Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/97749/how-to-simulate-a-rope

Comment: Hi, thanks so much! Really helpful!!!