# flexible straps in blender

Tags: cloth-simulation

I'm trying to make flexible straps that can be woven around objects and (if possible) also freely dangle in the air slightly when being animated.

I was thinking of using Cloth Simulator but I'm not sure it also allows you to wrap them around things?

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76756/how-to-animate-winding-a-ribbon-onto-a-cylinder and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48801/are-curve-physics-possible

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos true those are both related but I need something that can do both of those things, and each of those two articles aren't compatible with another :)

Comment: @Yaakov5777 it is easier to help you if you add information on what you have tried so far.

Comment: you might wish to look into "pinning".  this will allow you to specify certain vertices (a vertex group) of a cloth sim mesh that stay immobile while the rest of the object simulates cloth physics movement.  A clean way to animate simulated cloth that has been pinned is to parent the cloth mesh to an armature, even just a single bone.  The bone can be moved around / keyframed and the pinned vertices will follow the bone, while the unpinned vertices respond to gravity/collisions/forces.