# How to make power line cables hang and move with wind?

Tags: physics, soft-body

*Edited*

I made a curve path in the shape of wire hanging from two support beams, in a scene I'm creating. I want to incorporate wind simulations to affect the wires so that they sway to the side/in the direction of the wind. How would I go about doing? I've im not sure whether to use rigid body or soft body as I'm kinda new to this sort of thing. Any help appreciated, please!

Using Blender 2.82

I was linked this post
[Are curve physics possible?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48801/are-curve-physics-possible/48806#48806)

Although useful I still need help with making created wires get influenced by wind physics :)

Comment: The content should not be the title repeated. Maybe write what you've tried.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48801/are-curve-physics-possible/48806#48806

Comment: @Lukasz-40sth Sorry. I didn't know what else to put. I made a curve path in the shape of wire hanging from two support beams, in a scene I'm creating. I want to incorporate wind simulations to affect the wires so that they sway to the side/in the direction of the wind. How would I go about doing? I've im not sure whether to use rigid body or soft body as I'm kinda new to this sort of thing. Any help appreciated please!

Comment: Can't beat @DuarteFarrajotaRamos when it comes to pulling out his noodle answers.  Recommend studying his answer to dupe question, and if need be ask a more focused question (perhaps with blend file attached) re getting a wind force effect.  Would like to see answer, voted to re-open.

Comment: The described technique using a cloth modifier is compatible with wind force field simulation.

Comment: So from my understanding, if I was to pull it off I would convert my path to mesh, select vertices that I want to not be affected in a vertex group, then apply a cloth modifier?