# Creating cables that can drape over objects

Tags: cloth-simulation

I've been trying to create mic cables for a studio scene that can drape realistically over objects, and have had varying success creating a mesh line, extruding vertices to create the basic path and form for the cable, and then converting to a curve and beveling the curve to create a tube.

Then I've converted the tube back to mesh and used the physics tab to apply cloth to it. I've tinkered with various settings, like more or less subdivisions, greater & lesser tension/compression/bend values in the cloth, and it's coming out OK, but I'm having trouble getting the "cable" to not collapse or deform.

Figured out the pinning routine so I can easily pin the cable to the mic, created collision settings so it can drape nicely over a mic stand and floor, used subdivision surface to smooth out the final product, but can't quite get the cable to stay nice & round. Certain bend points tend to flatten out. How can I get the cable to maintain it's roundness?

Any suggestions...?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48801/are-curve-physics-possible

Answer (score 4):

You can do this wihout cloth simulation, use the ***Draw Curves*** tool.

Add a *Bézier* curve object.

In edit mode delete all vertices (<kbd>x</kbd>).

Select Draw Curve from the toolbox

[image]

Press <kbd>N</kbd> to bring out the properties region, and in the *Tool* tab set the Draw *Depth* to ***Surface***.

Then draw your curve freely.

[image]

Then set the curve to have some bevel, to make it the width you need.

[image]

You might need to adjust the *Tolerance* and *Detect Corner* values to fit your particluar needs.

For more detail on the tool read the manual:

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/curves/tools/draw.html?highlight=draw%20curve

Comment: Amazing! Exactly what I needed! thanks so much!

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Susu answer works for this, but maybe in general also check out the 'blender secrets' 1 min videos on cables. Just search on 'blender secrets cables' there are a few very good tips.