# Physic Simulation of copper Cable

Tags: armature, physics

I'm trying to model realistic physics of different copper cables in blender 2.92. My goal is to drop the Cables in a bin and see how they are deformed by collision.
I already tried a cloth and soft body simulation but then the cables are way to flexible.
now I'm trying to use armatures within my Cables but I'm not able to drop the objects in the bin and let them deformed by collision (picture).
Any ideas how I could simulate the cable?

[image]

Comment: *"I already tried a cloth and soft body simulation but then the cables are way to flexible"* - did you try tinkering with settings? Here's what I get by increasing stiffeness and decreasing vertex weight, still too flexible? https://i.imgur.com/70IHROb.gif

Comment: @Jesssi: You should really not give up after 5 minutes. Maybe watch some tutorials...task is not too hard...

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48801/are-curve-physics-possible/48806#48806

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady looks like the right direction. Is this just a vertex line with a cloth or a soft body? What parameters did you use for this Simulations?

Comment: Don’t forget to have everything at a realistic scale - a 10m length of copper will behave differently to a 10cm length. Also, don’t forget to ‘Apply Scale’ after resizing. Cloth with high value of ‘structure’ should be stiff enough, as would soft body with high bending spring strength.

Comment: The simple answer here is, *Blender physics are not realistic physics.*  They are tools for making pictures.  You have to cheat them to get the behavior you want; you have to know what you want beforehand.  They are definitely *not* tools to see how real things deform.  You can see how Blender makes things deform; in which case you've already done that, via cloth and soft body, you just didn't like it.

Comment: @Jesssi I already closed that project, but I believe it was a hexagonal (maybe octagonal?) cylinder with loopcuts distributed so that faces are roughly squares.