# Simulating Moving Wires on a Motorcycle Model

Tags: constraints

Edit: I solved it using this post [How to create a cable/wire for animation?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/121357/how-to-create-a-cable-wire-for-animation/)  However, when I copy/paste/append the bike into a new scene the cables with the cloth physics are distorted and not how they should be. How can I avoid this?

I am currently rigging the front end of a motorcycle and I was wondering how I could constrain the start and end point of the wire and have the rest move as it should. Here it is in its "rest" position.
[image]

[image]

[image: Also, ideally it would collide with this wire holder and any other mesh in the way.]

The second Picture is the wire in the rotated position.

Also, ideally it would collide with this wire holder and any other mesh in the way.

Is it possible to have this movement happen in real time while I move the front end?

Thanks!

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/97749/how-to-simulate-a-rope https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/121357/how-to-create-a-cable-wire-for-animation/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48801/are-curve-physics-possible/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm thinking that since a bicycle cable is rather stiff, I'd skip any physics solutions (more compute needed) for a simpler mesh *Hook* using a gradient vertex group, so that the handle-bar mesh area follows the handle bars more than the other (brake/frame) end.   Here is the cable in weight paint mode to display the strong to weak vertex weight distribution:
[image]

On the cable, I created a vertex group "handle bar gradient" that includes all vertices of the cable and (in Weight Paint mode) created the red (high weighted) to blue (low/zero weight) distribution.

I then added a Hook modifier to the handle bars, so that when I rotate around the Z axis, the cable would stretch and shrink and flex between its end-points, adjusting the falloff radius to be sure that the frame-end would never move away from the frame.

My example: [image]