How to make a mound of randomly twirling curves based of a mesh
so i want to make a bowl of pasta the one that looks like stripes from a base mesh of half a sphere using random curves how can i achieve this using geometry nodes or anyone with a better way
the look im going for is this:


The only good solution I see would be with physics, probably Soft Bodies. Otherwise it would be challenging to have no clipping between 2 pastas.

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48801/are-curve-physics-possible/48806#48806

true but that would mean a lot of subdivs

Not really, you can subdivide it just enough to get it to bend into an approximate shape, then once you're satifsfied with your simulation then you can subdivide it again to smooth it out fully.
